# Ignoring post processing is causing fog color issue on objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, post-processing

I have multiple layered cameras. One camera is the main one that renders everything with post processing effects (deferred rendering ), another is for ignoring post processing effects ( forward rendering ), another camera is for particle effects to ignore post processing but it needs soft particles as well so this one needs deferred rendering.

The issue I am running into is the fog is rendering as a different color for the objects that are ignoring the post processing on my ignore post processing camera and particle camera.

Is there any way to fix this fog issue? Is it being caused by how each camera frame is being rendered and stacked? I am very confused and have tried a million things to get this fixed with no luck. Not sure if this is a bug that the fog being applied to these objects are a different color than the normal fog color. Could there be a rendering trick to fix this without changing the rendering types for each camera?

I have tried adjusting all the different camera settings but nothing seems to be fixing the issue. Either the objects aren't rendering in the correct order, missing fog, ect. This might need to be a coding fix for the rendering stack for each camera.